# Can I convert a European washing machine to work with a North American outlet?

Tags: electrical, appliances

I'm looking to hook up a European washing machine I got my hands on to either a standard North American outlet (unlikely) or a 220 V appliance outlet.

Here's the info I have right now:

- 230V
- 50Hz
- 2300W

It has an s22 socket.

Comment: The most useful piece of information, is if the motor speed is controlled by some sort of micro-controller.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in North America the frequency is 60Hz, so I'm not sure how that would affect it.  The difference in voltage (220V compared to 230V) is probably not significant.

I'd check with the manufacturer to see if there would be any issues.

Comment: If it has a synchronous AC motor, it may not like 60Hz instead of 50Hz. I have no idea how likely that it does have a synchronous AC motor.